# C poll() times out repeatedly on OS X after machine wakes from sleep

Tags: c, macos, networking, tcp

I'm connecting to a TCP stream in C. Everything is working as expected, but I've noticed an issue on OS X (10.10.2) whereby if my machine is put to sleep and then woken, calls to `poll()` will timeout repeatedly.

Here's a simplified version of my listen loop:

```
while(should_keep_listening)
{
    struct pollfd fds[1];
    fds[0].fd = fd;
    fds[0].events = POLLIN;

    int pollrc = poll(fds, 1, 1000);

    // An error occurred
    if (pollrc == -1)
    {
        should_keep_listening = false;
    }
    // Our poll request timed out
    else if(pollrc == 0)
    {
        continue;
    }
    else if(fds[0].revents & POLLIN)
    {
        // read data...
    }
}
```

Upon resuming from sleep the machine will receive a `pollrc` value of 0 (a timeout), which is understandable. However, upon continue-ing, poll will then continue to timeout indefinitely, and fail to receive any additional data.

My first hunch was that there may be an issue with the file descriptor upon waking the machine, but a simple check seems to suggest the file descriptor is valid:

```
if(fcntl(fd, F_GETFL) != -1 || errno != EBADF)
{
    // File descriptor seems OK
}
```

Am I misunderstanding `poll's` behaviour? Or is there something I should be doing to prevent this sort of thing? The only solution I've found is to provide a fairly large timeout value (10 seconds), and reconnecting to the TCP stream when a timeout is reported, but this obviously isn't ideal!